# ConstraintLayout messes up after I change the src of an ImageView

Tags: android, xml

This is the first screenshot, where everything is working fine with a placeholder background.

[image]

This is the second screenshot, where the two ImageButtons don't display anymore.

[image]

For reference, here's my test xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bruisedbanana.squareshift.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/squareshiftbackground"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonPlay"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.952"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonExit" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonExit"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonExit"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.891" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

All I'm doing is changing the src from @drawable/squareshiftbackground to @drawable/realbackground. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `YourImageButton.bringToFront()` to the image butons after changing the ImageView source.